# Conversion of null to string in Java

Tags: java, string, null

Today I found a bug in legacy code, which led me to a shocking discovery:

```
String s = null + ""; //results in "null" string
s = String.valueOf(null); // NullPointerException is thrown
Integer i = null;
s = String.valueOf(i); //results in "null" string
```

First question is: Why such an unexpected behavior happens?
It mean that a convenient code like this:

```
String age = person.getAge() + "";
```

is being totally unexpected.
Second question: What is the best (most elegant) way to get a null instead of "null"

Answer (score 3):

`String.valueOf(null)` calls `public static String valueOf(char data[])` due to method overloading resolution rules (`char[]` is more specific than `Object`). That method throws `NullPointException` for a `null` argument.

`String.valueOf(i)` calls `public static String valueOf(Object obj)`, which returns the `String` "null" for a `null` argument.

To avoid this exception, either don't call `s = String.valueOf(null);` (you can always assign `s = "null";` directly, or cast the `null` value to some type other than `char[]` (for example `s = String.valueOf((String)null);`).

Comment: The exception bothers me less than an incorrect value being passed around in case you expect null, but instead get "null" string.

Comment: @Constant In that case, make sure you never concatenate a `null` to a `String` and never pass `null` to `String.valueOf()`.